# New column to flag the latest date per category?

Tags: powerbi, dax

| Transaction | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 9d134th328sf | 03/20/2022 |
| 3dhsafhur3fs | 01/20/2022 |
| 9d134th328sf | 01/22/2022 |
| 9d134th328sf | 02/20/2022 |
| 9d134th328sf | 01/02/2022 |
| 4dsa21dqf3df | 01/20/2022 |

As you see in the table above, "9d134th328sf" are duplicate transactions within a column found in multiple rows. How can I compare the records in Power BI row by row and then display it to say as "Yes" or "No" in a new column called Latest Transaction?

| Transaction | Date | Latest Transaction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9d134th328sf | 03/20/2022 | Yes |
| 3dhsafhur3fs | 01/20/2022 | Yes |
| 9d134th328sf | 01/22/2022 | No |
| 9d134th328sf | 02/20/2022 | No |
| 9d134th328sf | 01/02/2022 | No |
| 4dsa21dqf3df | 01/20/2022 | Yes |

I haven't tried anything that I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this **calculated column**:

```
Latest Transaction = 
VAR maxdate =
CALCULATE(
    MAX('ThisTable'[Date]), 
    ALLEXCEPT('ThisTable','ThisTable'[Transaction])
)
RETURN
    IF(ThisTable[Date] = maxdate, "Yes", "No")
```

[image]